# Links inside iframe stopped working with PhoneGap iOS 4.1.0

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, iframe, anchor

We have a `PhoneGap` application using `Ionic` framework. In this app we can have an `iframe` containing links with any target: `_parent`, `_top`, `_self`, ...

We capture the clicks with target `_parent`, `_top` and `_blank` to open them in a `browser`. We don't capture links with target `_self` or no target because we want them to be opened inside the `iframe`.

This worked fine when we were using version 3.9.1 for `platform-ios`, but when we updated to 4.1.0 the links with `_self` or no target stopped working for some reason. We click them and nothing happens. Nothing is written in the console either.

We have the following in the config.xml:

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
<access origin="*"/>
```

And the CSP in index.html:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * filesystem: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com; img-src * filesystem: gap: data: https://ssl.gstatic.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' filesystem: cdvfile: file:; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' http://localhost:* filesystem: cdvfile: file:">
```

Are we missing something in order to make it work?